# How do i implement highlighting for phonetic search in solr?

Tags: solr, highlight, phonetics

The case here is, when i search for a word eg. xyz it properly shows the field with highlighting tags but for others eg. abc, even though the word is part of searched field value, it doesn't do the highlighting at all.

```
    http://example.com:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=content_phonetic:country&hl=on&hl.tag.pre=<em>&hl.tag.post=</em>&hl.field=content_phonetic
```

The issue is inconsistency. For some search words it does the highlighting perfectly fine and for other no highlighting at all. 
Eg.

```
    &q=content_phonetic:original&hl.field=content_phoneic
```

this gives perfectly good highlighted result but

```
    &q=content_phonetic:country&hl.field=content_phoneic
```

this gives no highlighting at all, though content_phonetic field has both words in same line of text. 
Also for beiderMorseFilter that i am using, 
        "country" will be indexed as

```
    kountri 
    kuntri 
    tsountri 
    kountri
```

and "original" world will be indexed as

```
    oriZinal 
    oridZinal  
    original 
    orixinal
```

and again for "report" though the indexed word would be "report"

```
    &q=content_phonetic:report&hl.field=content_phoneic
```

this last one also gives no highlighting at all.

Comment: Is Solr returning the correct results when you search for "abc" and not showing the proper highlighting? or is Solr not even giving you the proper search results?

Comment: yes its giving proper search results, just highlighting not working as expected.
Lets say if i search 'abc' in "content" field , i get all the highlighting in the result.
But for if searched against field "content_phonetic" i still get all the results but not the highlighting.

Comment: Solr will only show highlight info for fields listed in `hl_fl`. Is the field where the value that is not highlighted ("abc") in a field indicated in `hl_fl` ?